# not getting equivalent UI design in my WinForms Window

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I converted my VB and Winforms Based application to C# and WinForms. I am observing that I am unable to replicate the exact same Window **Design(Border)** in my C# application.

I have checked the properties of the window as well as every element in the C# and have compared it with the VB window property and they are all same but why I am getting a different UI for my C# application.

The VB Window Looks like this

[image]

The  C# application is like this currently

[image]

As I can see that there is the **border** missing as well as the **bordercolor**. How can I fix it ?

Comment: Have you got the calls to 'EnableVisualStyles()' etc?

Comment: No I havent done this. Do i need to do it for every window ? can you help me with the code ?

Comment: @DavidOsborne the calls are there in the Program.cs files

Comment: What is your FormBorderStyle? Default is sizable.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock its FixedSizeWindow

Answer (score 0):

In VB EnableVisualStyles is tucked away in Application.myapp but it needs to be set prior to creating your forms. So when your C# app starts make sure you call

```
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
```

Beyond this it's the Operating system which handles the window border styles through themes (hence why the winforms designer vs the run time generally shows different borders)

Comment: where do I need to add these lines ?

Comment: @Apoorv In `Program.cs` Main Method

Comment: I just checked , these lines are there in the Program.cs